# How to write and execute programs in terminal/command prompt?

Tags: ide, console

For example:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tKTZoB2Vjuk (@ 5 min)

I have no idea how one would go about writing code and making it work without an IDE but it seems like a useful thing to know how to do. Thanks!

Comment: vague...  define "code"?

Comment: basically what i am asking is, is there a way for me to open command prompt and somehow let it know what program language i want it to interpret and then start executing code.(in C++: cout >> 4 + 8;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open an editor. Edit the code. Invoke the compiler. Run the executable.

Can't say much more without further details on your part.

What they're showing in the video though is the Python [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop).

Comment: Basically this is the only way i know how to write a program:open codeblocks(or eclipse, visual studieo, etc), write code, compile.

Comment: @Matt: If the language doesn't have a REPL then that's the only way to do it.